# If statement/checkvalue?

Tags: c#, if-statement, email

I have Googled my fingers bare on this one and I know that the code here isn't very acceptable but i'd really appreciate some help:

This checkbox has to go and check a value (boolean) of an option button.

Display a different message depending on that value and if True include an extra line in a mail, but thats another problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really need to get the hang of this C#.

```
public void field42_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)
{
    // checking Gsm checkbox(IOgsm@parzs.be)
    if (e.NewValue.Equals("true"))
    {
        XPathNavigator xnMyForm = this.CreateNavigator();
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = this.NamespaceManager;
        xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:txtGSM", ns).SetValue("P.Bab@gmail.Com");
        //string MobielInternet = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:GsmMobileInternet", ns).Value;
        if MobielInternet e.NewValue.Equals("true")
            MessageBox.Show("An e-mail for GSM with Mobile internet will be sent");
        if (e.NewValue.Equals("false"))
            MessageBox.Show("An email for the GSM will be sent");
        if (e.NewValue.Equals(""))
            MessageBox.Show (" The Mobile Internet option has to been filled out ");
    }
    else if (e.NewValue.Equals("false"))
    {
        XPathNavigator xnMyForm = this.CreateNavigator();
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = this.NamespaceManager;
        xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:txtGSM", ns).SetValue("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't really given a good description of the problem - you've said what you want it to do, and given some code... so what's going wrong? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: if MobielInternet e.NewValue.Equals("true") has incorrect parenthesis.

Comment: yes but i got its value through a value from node as in ",//string MobielInternet = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:GsmMobileInternet ns).Value;                    if MobielInternet e.NewValue.Equals("true")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my suggestion for cleaner code. I'm hoping I'm not missing the point here, but you aren't actually comparing the mobielinternet value, you were comparing the EventArgs value again.

Try this.

```
XPathNavigator xnMyForm = this.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager ns = this.NamespaceManager;
var emailAddress = "";
var message = "";

if (e.NewValue.Equals("true"))
{
    emailAddress = "P.Bab@gmail.Com";
    string MobielInternet = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:GsmMobileInternet", ns).Value;

    if (string.IsNullorEmpty(MobielInternet))
        message = "The Mobile Internet option has to been filled out";

    if (bool.Parse(MobielInternet))
        message = "An e-mail for GSM with Mobile internet will be sent";
    else
        message = "An email for the GSM will be sent";

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
else if (e.NewValue.Equals("false"))
{
    XPathNavigator xnMyForm = this.CreateNavigator();
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = this.NamespaceManager;
    xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:txtGSM", ns).SetValue("");
}


xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:txtGSM", ns).SetValue(emailAddress);
```